# Building tags using Continuous Integration

Tags: svn, version-control, jenkins, continuous-integration, configuration-management

How could I establish practice of continuously integrating tags instead of branches?

I have following structure of tags repository directory ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829/structure-of-projects-in-version-control/8929709#8929709) is more detailed explanation of the repository structure):

```
/tags
    /builds
        /PA
        /A
        /B
    /releases
        /AR
        /BR
        /RC
        /ST
```

I would like to configure my continuous integration tool (it could be anything from CruiseControl, Hudson and Jenkins to TeamCity) to build latest tag if it has been created in either of those folders.

For example, if structure has changed and tag `1.x.0` has appeared in `PA` directory, I want to trigger building of source code under `1.x.0` tag:

```
/tags
    /builds
        /PA
            /1.x.0 -> triggers build
        /A
        /B
    /releases
        /AR
        /BR
        /RC
        /ST
```

Is it possible to build source under tags with any of the existing continuous integration tools or I should write my own plugin for that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Jenkins: use a periodic job to check for new tags, then use the [Parametrized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to kick off your job with the tag as a parameter. The job will manually update to the tag and build.

Comment: @melankiy_scot How do i set up the periodic job to check for new tags? Do i use a plugin for that?

Comment: @ziggy, I meant something more lightweight, like a script. For example, in SVN the command `svn ls [REPO_URL]/tags` will give you the contents of `tags`, you can store it for comparison the next time the job is run. Of course you can use a plugin to poll for repository modifications and run your job (that runs the script) only when `tags` directory is modified.

Comment: i am using CVS so a script is probably the only option

Answer (score 0):

With Jenkins (Hudson) and Subversion you can have a tag that is constant e.g `tags/BUILD`. When anything with the tag changes, Jenkins will build based on that tag. You can then ask it to apply a new tag after the build.

In your example, you can create a new tag as `tags/builds/PA` and have Jenkins listen to that tag. Jenkins will detect any changes in the `tags/builds/PA` folder and will build if it detects any changes. You can configure a post build step to create a new tag (1.x.0) when it completes the build.

I posted a similar question on the topic and got some responses here - http://groups.google.com/group/jenkinsci-users/browse_thread/thread/59ca7f0f9e21a382/fe14fc7269611b26#fe14fc7269611b26

Comment: The point is that I want to create `1.x.0` tag manually, not with continuous integration tool. Morevover, committing to the tags directory (as you suggest to commit into `tags/BUILD`) is deprecated.